# Duplicates when searching by text_general

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

I'm using Solr 8, and run it with almost default configuration. I would like to search over several text field, and copy them into _text_general_ field.

This is parts of my managed_schema.xml:

```
<field name="id" type="string" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="p_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="p_additional_info" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="p_brand" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="p_manufacturer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="p_image_link" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<!-- copy this 3 values to basic search field -->
<copyField source="p_name" dest="_text_"/>
<copyField source="p_brand" dest="_text_"/>
<copyField source="p_additional_info" dest="_text_"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I'm trying to get results with `q=*:*` it gives me no duplicates. By when I'm trying to obtain results with `q=men` i see following:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"men",
      "_":"1555579368807"}},
  "response":{"numFound":9,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "p_additional_info":"A creme especially made for men, suitable for face, body and hands.",
        "p_name":"NIVEA MEN CREME",
        "id":"16",
        "_version_":1630705876203470848},
      {
        "p_additional_info":"A creme especially made for men, suitable for face, body and hands.",
        "p_name":"NIVEA MEN CREME",
        "id":"16",
        "_version_":1630702978343108608},
        ...            
]}}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve it?..

**UPD**
I'm importing my documents via DIH from DB:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://mydb.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/myapp" user="***" password="***" readOnly="true" />
    <document>
          <entity name="products"
                  query="select id, additional_info, brand, name, image_link, country, manufacturer from products"
                  dataSource="jdbc" pk="id"> 

            <field name="id" column="id" />
            <field name="p_additional_info" column="additional_info" />
            <field name="p_brand" column="brand" />
            <field name="p_name" column="name" />
            <field name="p_country" column="country" />
            <field name="p_manufacturer" column="manufacturer" />
            <field name="p_image_link" column="image_link" />

          </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Here the _version_ for the documents is different...which shows that even though you have a uniqueKey as id, its not updating the existing document ...its adding another with different version...currently you have String type for the field id ...Try by changing it integer...

Comment: ...also it is not indexed...first try to make the indexed to true and then try later option

Comment: No that is an assumption ! The "string" type is ok for the uniqueKey, and the implicit default for `indexed` property is `"true"` both for field and fieldType definitions, so as long as your "string" fieldType does not have an explicit `indexed="false"`, `id` should be indexed. Also remember not to make manual edits to a managed-schema but to use the schema API instead.

Comment: @EricLavault : Yes..good catch...I verified ..the indexed attribute is implicitly true for the fields defined

Comment: How are you adding documents to Solr?

Comment: @EricLavault you're right. uniqueKey indexed by default. I've just checked it

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti looks like I can't use any of integer types, because even TrieIntField is deprecated, like all of other numeric types, but Point field cannot be used as uniqueKey :(

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm importing all data via DIH from my DB. I've updated the question with DIH config. Most strange thing, that q=*:* returns NO duplicates, when search by text does..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was some bug in my managed_schema when I made manual changes. After I created new one and made the changes via schema API, as @EricLavault supposed, everything works properly.